# Why might you call instance_eval (as opposed to class_eval) inside 'initialize'?

Tags: ruby

```
  class Observer
    def initialize(&block)
      instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
    end
  end
```

I'm wondering what assumption is made here about the type of block that is being used with 'initialize'.

Since instance_eval is called, this means the block is evaluated in the context of the class Observer.

Why would it do that, as opposed to, say, class_eval and what is likely to be the outcome of evaluating a block in the context of the class?

Also, how would this be invoked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you can't do something like this:

```
class Observer
  def initialize(&block)
    class_eval(&block) if block_given?
  end
end
```

Because `class_eval` isn't defined for an instance of `Observer`.  It is defined in `Module` (which `Class` descends from).  We'll come back to `class_eval` later.

The reason to use the above idiom is often to allow block initialization:

```
x = Observer.new do
  add_event(foo)
  some_other_instance_method_on_observer
  self.some_attribute = something
end
```

Plus, you can add methods to a given instance of the class:

```
foo = Observer.new do
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

foo.foo  # => "foo"
```

You can accomplish roughly the same thing without `instance_eval`:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

foo = Foo.new do |x|
  x.add_event(foo)
  x.some_other_instance_method_on_observer
  x.self.some_attribute = something
end
```

But that doesn't give you the ability to add methods.  If you were to do this:

```
foo = Foo.new do
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

foo.foo  # => "foo"
```

It seems to work, right?  But what you've actually done is to add the `foo` method to everything, because `self` is set to the "main" object.  It's equivalent to simply defining the method outside of the block.  They get added as instance methods to `Object`, so they work on everything.

Now, as promised, a brief return to `class_eval`.  You *could* do something like this:

```
class Observer
  def initialize(&block)
    class.class_eval(&block) if block_given?
  end
end
```

But then you open up the entire class:

```
x = Observer.new { def foo; 'foo'; end }
x.foo                                      # => "foo"
y = Observer.new
y.foo                                      # => "foo"
```

This isn't typically what we want to do.  Plus, `self` will be the class, not the instance.  This makes it useless for the block initialization as demonstrated above.

Comment: @belgariontheking nah, try finding this much concise info properly presented on the ruby docs - you'll have some fun gathering and sorting it to come to this (imo) short and well explained answer :) (Not to mention this is actually still relevant roughly 9 and a half years later)

Answer (score 2):

One use-case would be setting the state of the observer within its context.

Perhaps

```
o = Observer.new do
      listen_to(<some object>)
      report_to(<something>)
    end
```

Such use would not work with a class_eval, which could only access class state

Answer (score 0):

Initialize is an instance method. It's executed in the context of an instance, not the class itself. Thus `instance_eval` causes the block to execute in the context of the instance as well.

There is no such thing as `class_eval` in a normal object instance — it's only defined for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because the **initialize** method is an instance method and **class_eval** is defined for objects of type **Class** which means they can be executed only in class methods or inside the class body.

So the following snippet of code will raise an error:

> "".class_eval{methods} #=>
>   NoMethodError: undefined method
>   `class_eval' for "":String

While this one will just work:

```
s.class.class_eval{methods} #=> ["methods", "respond_to?", "module_eval", "class_variables", "dup", "instance_variables", "protected_instance_methods", "__id__", "public_method_defined?", "eql?", "object_id", "const_set", "id", "singleton_methods", "send", "class_eval", "taint", "include?", "private_instance_methods", "frozen?", "instance_variable_get", "private_method_defined?", "__send__", "instance_of?", "name", "to_a", "autoload", "type", "new", "protected_methods", "instance_eval", "display", "instance_method", "instance_variable_set", "kind_of?", "protected_method_defined?", "extend", "const_defined?", "to_s", "ancestors", "public_class_method", "allocate", "class", "<=>", "hash", "<", "tainted?", "private_methods", "==", "instance_methods", "===", "class_variable_defined?", ">", "nil?", "untaint", "constants", ">=", "is_a?", "autoload?", "<=", "inspect", "private_class_method", "const_missing", "method", "clone", "=~", "public_instance_methods", "public_methods", "method_defined?", "superclass", "instance_variable_defined?", "equal?", "freeze", "included_modules", "const_get"]
```